# What are the differences between the final campaign boss in the original Borderlands and in the GOTY Edition?

Tags: borderlands-goty-edition

The final campaign boss, "The Destroyer" in *Borderlands: Game of the Year Edition* has been reported to be "[tougher](https://www.polygon.com/2019/3/28/18285611/borderlands-remastered-game-of-the-year-edition-pc-ps4-xbox-one-release-date)," and "[more challenging, engaging and rewarding](https://web.archive.org/web/20190330155714/https://segmentnext.com/2019/03/29/borderlands-remaster/)" than its previous iteration in the original *Borderlands*.

What are the differences between the final boss in the original *Borderlands* and in the *GOTY Edition*?

Comment: considering GotY was just released, and it takes quite a while to complete the campaign, i don't expect anyone to have this information yet. only thing i can really say is play through the game and find out yourself.
(ik that's not really helpful, but seeing as it's been 14 hours i'm gonna guess no one knows)

Comment: @EarthToAccess It's been released for 10 days now. I've beaten the final boss in GOTYE, however I don't know how it's different from the original Borderlands since it's been years since I last played the original.

Comment: @EarthToAccess the game has been on PS4 for over a week, and has already been platinumed (therefore,  completed) by quite a few players.

Comment: hmm, interesting. took me about a month to complete the original game.
might just be me being a minority in this case then lol